# ESP8266, Vcc and CH_PD oscilation

Tags: esp8266, oscillation

First, sorrry for my bad english :(

I'm having problems with ESP when I connect CH_PD with 3.3v

My circuit is this:

Simulator: https://123d.circuits.io/circuits/1539895-the-unnamed-circuit/edit#breadboard

[image: Circuit A]

The problem in the simulation is: When I connect Vcc only, the ESP turns on the led. When I connect the CH_PD pin, the voltage oscilates between 3.3V and 960mV.

In the real word, the ESP red led turns blinks only one time. With my voltimeter, I only see 960mV

When I use an Arduino UNO to provide 3.3v to Vcc and CH_PD, I have no problem.

Someone know why I'm having this problem? In google I cannot found anything.

Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, please provide a schematic. It is very difficult to understand those awful picture diagram things.

Your issue is that you are using a voltage divider where you should have a voltage regulator. The voltage divider provides 3.3V with no load, but when the ESP draws current, the voltage drops. Ohm's law can tell you why.

The solution: use an actual 3.3V regulator, and make sure to adequately decouple it (the ESP can draw very large spikes of current, particularly when transmitting).

Answer (score 2):

You have current limited your ESP8266 in your diagram because you have a 1k resistor in series with the ESP8266 VCC (At least from the pinouts that I found on google, I don't know if you have the same board). I wouldn't expect anything to work in this design